# object is passed as an argument not declared

Tags: java

The problem with this code is that whenever i run this it shows the compilation error:

> cannot find symbol:constructor mywindowadapter(frame1)
>
> location:class mywindowadapter
>
> mywindowadapter mwa=new mywindowadapter()"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code=frame2 width=500 height=500>
</applet>*/
class frame2 extends Frame
{
    frame2(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        mywindowadapter mwa=new mywindowadapter();
        addWindowListener(mwa);     
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        frame2 f=new frame2("my frame");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,100);
    
     }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("hello frame",60,70);
    }
}
class mywindowadapter extends WindowAdapter
{

    mywindowadapter()
    {
        frame2 f=new frame2();  
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        f.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The code below is the rectified version of the above code. i am not able to understand the error generated in the previous code. please help!!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/*<applet code=frame2 width=500 height=500>
</applet>*/
class frame2 extends Frame
 {
    frame2(String title)
    {
        super(title);
        mywindowadapter mwa=new mywindowadapter(this);
        addWindowListener(mwa);     
    }
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        frame2 f=new frame2("my frame");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(200,100);
    
    }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("hello frame",60,70);
    }
}
class mywindowadapter extends WindowAdapter
{
    frame2 f;
    mywindowadapter(frame2 f)
    {
        this.f=f;   
    }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
    {
        f.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you get this error message, it's not when compiling the code you show.

Comment: its while compiling the error is displayed , i have checked.

Comment: The error message says: "mywindowadapter(frame1)". And you have zero occurrence of frame1 in the code of the first snippet. Zero class and zero variable is named like that. You're not compiling the code you think, or the message doesn't come from this code.

Comment: srry for the confusion before  i hav reedited it now.. and now it gives compilation error in the first one..:)

Comment: hello, i have one query regarding registring listeners, say i am using check boxes and do not write addItemListener(), if i now check or uncheck the checkbox its state doesnt change immediately but whenever i maximize my window or minimze it and again restore it that change gets reflected i.e- its state changes , i dont understand this, shud the state of checkbox not change since we are not registring listener. please help .

Answer (score 0):

frame2 doesn't have a default constructor and you are trying to use it in your adapter.

Either provide a default constructor for frame2 or pass appropriate argument to the existing one.

First code certainly has many compilation errors, please fix them. Like in windowClosing() you cannot refer to f.

Comment: thnx.. but my question to you y i have to explicitly provide the default constructor y it cannot implcitly invoke the constructor that jvm provides.

Comment: jvm provides default constructor only when you do not provide any. in your case you have one constructor that takes in string. so you also need to provide default one if you want to use it.

Comment: hello, i have one query regarding registring listeners, say i am using check boxes and do not write addItemListener(), if i now check or uncheck the checkbox its state doesnt change immediately but whenever i maximize my window or minimze it and again restore it that change gets reflected i.e- its state changes , i dont understand this, shud the state of checkbox not change since we are not registring listener. please help .

Comment: Ideally, listeners should not affect the state unless you are capturing state change event and resetting it.

Comment: hello, i have a problem in setting class path in commnd prompt. what i am doing is  i  set the class path using set classpath=C:\Events from the cd which is - c:\awt .the actual code is this-c:\awt>set classpath=C:\Events,then i compile and run the file and it runs ok but class file is not made in Events folder also when i do echo%CLASSPATH% it reflects the above class path. so why that class file is not made in Events folder . please help.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like you have two versions of the `mywindowadapter` class one with a constructor having argument and other with constructor with no arguments. And the both are in the same package. So when compiling the `mywindowadapter` with no argument constructor is overwriting the other one.

Also there is a possibility that the class with constructor having argument is not in the package where you are calling the its constructor.

Check if its one of these cases.

Comment: hello, i have one query regarding registring listeners, say i am using check boxes and do not write addItemListener(), if i now check or uncheck the checkbox its state doesnt change immediately but whenever i maximize my window or minimze it and again restore it that change gets reflected i.e- its state changes , i dont understand this, shud the state of checkbox not change since we are not registring listener. please help!!

Comment: @AkshayMehra: Can you explain what do you mean by state of the check box. Is it the check mark you are talking about?
Also listeners are used to fire events on the state change. Are you trying to fire any events?

Comment: @AkshayMehra: Also I tried running your first code. I am not getting the error you have specified. Instead, you have two different errors. 
1.) Your frame2 f variable should be declared in the class not in the constructor.
2.) You are calling a no argument constructor of f2 which does not exist.

Comment: say i am unchecking the checkbox hence its state its false which i display using getState(), if i do not use addItemListener() then the changed state is reflected on the window using the above mentioned procedure but if i use addItemListener() then the changed state is immediately reflected on the window, so can u plzz explain how this whole process happening.\